# NPM registry not updated

Tags: node.js, registry, npm

I have created npm package for my the project. I have pushed its next version and committed in github.

After that. I executed

```
npm publish
```

in the project directory. But I see my NPM registry page has not updated README / LICENSE / VERSION.

When I execute

```
npm install packagename
```

It does install latest version but I'm worried about outdated README and VERSION displayed on NPM Registry.

How can I get it updated?

Link for package I'm expecting to update:- https://npmjs.org/package/jsmart

Comment: try updating node and npm https://github.com/isaacs/npm-www/issues/105

Comment: I'm already on the latest version. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Today I can see package is updated. I think it does take some time to clear the cache/update with new values.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a **suffix** for the current version of the package
example :
let's say the current version of your package is *1.0.0*,

you have two options :

**option1:**

change the version manually,change it to something line *1.0.1*
and then publish it by using the command :

```
npm publish
```

**note :** In this case you may get an error saying that your github repo is not clean (due to the manual updating), so it is better to use the second option

**option2:**

change the version automatically.Type in your terminal:

```
npm version patch
```

to change just the last number(in this case the last 0 and increment it by 1).
Now you are ready to publish the new version of the package, so type in the terminal :

```
npm publish
```

and that's it

Answer (score 0):

Another reason can be inconsistencies in your package.json compared to the previous versions - such as different package name.

(it happened to me when e.g. publishing packages generated with swagger)

Answer (score 0):

For me I had 2 package.json files. One in the root of my project and another in a ./packages folder. I updated the version to both be the same and performed a git commit/push

> git commit -a

> git push

and npm publish

> npm publish